# pager js data-bind="page-href:{}" gives me a page is null

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pagerjs

I am new to knockout.js and pager.js. I have set

pager.js `data-bind="page-href:{}"` in one of my link. However, it gives me this error:

> a page is null

Answer (score 1):

I have defined here how to make a complete application with pager.js. You can visit this link

[PagerJS how to build a navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284585/pagerjs-how-to-build-a-navbar)

Answer (score 1):

The `page-href`-binding should either be a path (e.g. `page-href="some/page"`), an object with a path-parameter (e.g. `page-href={path: "some/page"}` or a page-instance (e.g. `page-href=$data` where $data is a page-instance).

See http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/navigation/relative_path for examples.