# Pagerjs and knockout, SPA file structure

Tags: knockout.js, pagerjs

I'm struggling to understand how to use pagerjs and knockout to structure my app correctly. I'm looking to have separate viewmodels to be included with each page reference.

Here's 3 pages within my index.html example:

```
         <div data-bind="page: {
                            id: 'page_1', 
                            title: 'page 1', 
                            source: 'views/page1.html',
                            with: page1ViewModel
                            }">
            </div>

            <div data-bind="page: {
                            id: 'page_2', 
                            title:'Page 2', 
                            source: 'views/page2.html',
                            with: page2ViewModel
                            }">
            </div>

            <div data-bind="page: {
                            id: 'page_3', 
                            title:'Page 3', 
                            source: 'views/page3.html',
                            with: page3ViewModel
                            }">
            </div>
```

So I have my page html split up into a views folder and this works well. What I'm really struggling to understand is how to store all my viewmodels in separate files and how that works with pagerjs.

If I was just using one viewmodel in a 'main.js', it would look like this:

```
function viewModel() {

}

var viewModel = new viewModel();
// use #!/ instead of the default #
pager.Href.hash = '#!/';

// extend viewModel with a $__page__ that points to pager.page that points to a new Page
pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
// apply your bindings
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
// run this method - listening to hashchange
pager.start();
```

Any help in structuring this with logical separation of view models would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can see complete structure [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284585/pagerjs-how-to-build-a-navbar)

Comment: I don't see any separation of viewmodels in separate files?

Comment: Is this reliant on requirejs also?

Answer (score 0):

Full example site here:
https://github.com/maxfridbe/WindowKO-TS-JS/tree/master/CleanWeb

Basically Knockout Pager and Typescript

i wrap the page: makepage() with my own makepage binding, which takes declarative convention based structure: ie makepage('bob') has this structure

will place a !#/bob

```
/area folder

    /views folder

   /view models folder
```